# How to Reduce Flutter APK size at least to 75% of the actual size?

Tags: flutter

Please what is the best way to reduce a Flutter app to the least size. Most things were simple integrations, then a Credit card payment gateway, nothing else, and its 80MB how can I reduce it to the least size , say 50MB or 40MB

Sought several things on the internet, could not find anything useful.

Comment: Removing unused dependencies, perhaps?

Comment: It's 80MB on release mode??

Comment: @VincentDR Debug. Is it always like this on Debug?

Comment: see https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/app-size#debug-builds-are-not-representative and https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/app-size#reducing-app-size

Comment: @Pamela Yes, debug is not optimized so you got a big apk. Release use optimisations to reduce app size, way under 75%.

Comment: Remove `assets` that haven't been used and check pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Where `flutter build apk` command make an apk in 50MB,
there`flutter build apk --split-per-abi` command will make this apk 5MB. You can try this.

Comment: Would it generate a single file?

Comment: You'll see output like below 

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          20.3s

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (5.1MB).

Comment: "app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk" is your apk. You can rename it as your wish.

Answer (score 0):

Upload .aab (Android App Bundle) instead of .apk file to the Play Store.
It reduces the download size for the users.
For more info refer [link description here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size#app_bundle)

Your APK might contain content that users download but never use, like additional language or per-screen-density resources. To ensure a minimal download for your users, you should upload your app to Google Play using Android App Bundles. Uploading app bundles lets Google Play generate and serve optimized APKs for each user’s device configuration, so they download only the code and resources they need to run your app.